# QNetworkAccessManager and DNS resolution

Tags: qt, http, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm using `qnetworkaccessmanager` for making `HTTP` requests. The hostname (**FQDN**) of the server I connect to, has two `IP addresses` in `DNS` and I need to control which one to use. The obvious solution (`change the URL's hostname to IP address`) does not work, because the `server` sends back a `302 redirect` with the original `hostname` in the location field. If I follow the `redirect`, **QT** seems to randomly choose which **IP** it connects to.

Is there a way to tell `qnetworkaccessmanager` to use a given `IP address` on the `TCP` `connect()` level and use the `Host header` from the `URL` ? If not, any workaround suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: using QT 4.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work and is a simple workaround: set the QNetworkRequest's URL to contain the desired IP address to connect to in the host part, but also use setCustomHeader("Host", "<server hostname>") to avoid the redirection. In my tests, QT will always use the IP set in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a custom `QNetworkRequest` and specify the `QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader` to force a specific destination URL in case of a redirect. If you look at `QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest` ([QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest doc)](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sendCustomRequest), and `QNetworkRequest::Attribute::RedirectionTarget` and `QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders` it should give you some hints about it.

(footnote: I'm using the harmattan documentation as the proper Qt documentation is down as of time of answer)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it will not do what I'm looking for. sendCustomRequest() is designed for HTTP verbs other than the usual GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. Also, the Location header and redirection target is only relevant for responses. I need to modify the request so that I can control which IP it will be sent to and get a non-302 response for it.

Comment: I was just about to write a response and see you've solved it anyway.